# "cout" should display front and rear of queue,instead it is displaying the value of "val" in push function and "line1" in scanitall function.Why?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, queue, file-handling

I have been trying to debug this code for over two weeks now..
This code is part of my project "offline system crawler".For now,the functioning of concern is:

1. The "scanitall" function opens the file "outputproject.txt" and inserts all its elements line by line into a queue defined by global variables "*front" and "*rear" which are of node type.
2. After creating the queue, the function "processit" further takes the file "inputproject.txt" lines as argument and then identifies the links in the file(Links are of type ** link ** in the text file) and further appends it to "outputproject.txt".
   **Now the problem is that the cout in the push always displays the value of "val"
   (instead of "rear->value" and "front->value")
    that is passed to the function as an argument, similarly "scanitall" function's cout is displaying the value of "line1"
   (instead of "rear->value" and "front->value")**

   ```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<fstream>
   #include<string.h>
   #include<stdio.h>
   using namespace std;
   ifstream infile;
   ofstream outfile;
   struct node
   {
       struct node *next;
       char *value;
   }*front,*rear;
   /*struct node * createnode(char *val)
   {
       struct node *new1=new node;
       new1->next=NULL;
       new1->value=val;
       return new1;
   }*/
   void push(char *val)
   {
       cout<<"\nPush Called with argument : "<<val<<endl;
       if(front && rear)
           cout<<"\nPush called->rear->"<<rear->value<<"->front->"<<front->value<<" val-> "<<val<<endl;
       struct node *new1=new node;
       new1->next=NULL;
       new1->value=val;
       if(front==NULL && rear==NULL)
       {
           rear=new node;
           front=new node;
           rear=new1;
           front=new1;
           cout<<"\nCreated a node 1\n";
       }
       else
       {
           rear->next=new1;
           rear=rear->next;
           //front->next=NULL;
           cout<<"\ncreated a node 2\n";
       }
       cout<<"Rear->"<<rear->value<<" =>> Front->"<<front->value<<"\n";
   }
   /*char *pop()
   {
       cout<<"Pop called\n";
       char *ch;
       if(front==NULL)
           return NULL;
       else if(front==rear)
       {
           ch=front->value;
           front=NULL;
           rear=NULL;
           return ch;
       }
       else
       {
           ch=front->value;
           front=front->next;
           return ch;
       }
   }*/
   void scanitall()
   {
       cout<<"scanitall called\n";
       string line;
       infile.open("outputproject.txt");
       while(getline(infile,line))
       {
           char line1[100];
           strncpy(line1, line.c_str(), sizeof(line1));
           line1[sizeof(line1) - 1] = 0;
           if(rear)
               cout<<"\n--------Rear->"<<rear->value<<"--------front->"<<front->value<<"-----\n";
           else
               cout<<"\n----------Rear empty at this time---------\n";
           push(line1);
       }
       infile.close();
   }
   void processit(char *abc)
   {
       // cout<<"PRocess it called\n";
       outfile.open("outputproject.txt",ios::app);
       if(!outfile)
           cout<<"Error file not opened!";
       int i,len,flag=0;
       len=strlen(abc);
       for(i=0;i<len;i++)
       {
           if(abc[i]=='*' && abc[i+1]=='*' && flag==0)
           {
               flag=1;
               i+=2;
           }

           if(abc[i]=='*' && abc[i+1]=='*' && flag==1)
           {
               outfile<<endl;
               flag=0;
               i+=2;
           }

           if(flag==1)
               outfile<<abc[i];
       }
       outfile.close();
   }
   void display(char *line)
   {
       // cout<<"display called\n";
       string line2;
       char ch;
       infile.open(line);
       if(!infile)
           cout<<"File not opened!  ";
       while(getline(infile,line2))
       {
           cout<<line2;
           cout<<endl;
       }
       cout<<endl;
       cout<<endl;
       infile.close();
   }
   void openallfiles()
   {
       // cout<<"openallfiles called\n";
       string line;
       char line1[100];
       infile.open("outputproject.txt");
       while(getline(infile,line))
       {
           strncpy(line1, line.c_str(), sizeof(line1));
           line1[sizeof(line1) - 1] = 0;
           display(line1);
       }
       infile.close();
   }
   int main()
   {
       front=NULL;
       rear=NULL;
       scanitall();
       string line;
       char line1[100];
       infile.open("inputproject.txt");
       while(getline(infile,line))
       {
           strncpy(line1, line.c_str(), sizeof(line1));
           line1[sizeof(line1) - 1] = 0;
           processit(line1);
       }
       infile.close();
       openallfiles();
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: The problem is that you're storing dangling pointers (`push(line1)`) so your program is undefined (most likely, all your `value`s are identical). Your problems will go away if you stick to `std::string`.

Comment: @molbdnilo sir, I am using "using namespace std" in the code

Comment: The fully qualified name of the class is still `std::string`.

Comment: sir, but i have already used this type of syntax many times earlier (also created queues in the same format)...Never experienced this issue earlier

Comment: Undefined behavior is exactly that, _anything_ can happen including it _working exactly as you want_ which is the scariest of all as it leads you to assuming it works at all. C++ is like that.

Comment: Oh, we've misunderstood each other completely. Sorry about that. I meant that you should stop using `char*` and use `string` throughout the program. How you name the string class is not the issue.

Comment: so should i use string instead of char* everywhere in the code?

Comment: I thought c and c++ do not have strings ,Java has

Comment: @AakashBansal What do you think the `string` class that you're using is?

Comment: According to my understanding, it is used for functions like strcmpi,strlen,etc.. for char* or char[ ]

Comment: sir, Apart from std::string ,are there any other flaws that you noticed?